# Filter and shuffle map in groovy

Tags: groovy

Get a list of orders in a payload as below, here are the steps needed in groovy. Appreciate help from experts

- 1. Filter cbp orders
- 2. Randomly shuffle cbp orders
- 3. Filter non cbp orders
- 4. New order list = shuffled cbp orders (first) + non cbp orders in the end

  {
  "orders": {
  "30001": {"id": "a1212", "program": "cbp"},
  "30452": {"id": "l0000", "program": "ll"},
  "30003": {"id": "a1421", "program": "cbp"},
  "32818": {"id": "a1212", "program": "cbp"},
  "40281": {"id": "88ds1", "program": "alm"}
  }
  }

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.